# Strip out string from string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a *string* like this

```
orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum, neque eu 
varius placerat, <p class="how-pkg"> leo diam viverra velit, </p> a commodo 
nibh metus nec orci. Nulla pharetra ut augue quis blandit.
```

I want to strip out a string value which is inside this `<p class="how-pkg"> ------ </p>`

Is there any way to accomplish this straight ahead?

without splitting the *string multiple times*.

Expected out put :`leo diam viverra velit,`

Comment: Do you only have one such tag in your string? Or can there be more?

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only string operations.

```
var searchForStart = "<p class=\"how-pkg\">";
int startIndex = input.IndexOf(searchForStart ) + searchFor.Length;
var searchForStop = "</p>";
int stopIndex = input.IndexIf(searchForStop, startIndex);

var output = text.Substring(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex);
```

Answer (score 4):

use html agility pack and write

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourText);
var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/p[@class='how-pkg']").InnerText;
```

Comment: `doc` is `string` in this case?

Comment: @SonerGönül nope, it's HtmlDocument from HtmlAgilityPack <- I've added creation of object to answer

Comment: +1 Also `"/p[@class='how-pkg']"` selector can be more appropriate if suddenly there will be other tags

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy thanks, added more specific selector

Answer (score 1):

Assuming source is a your string:

```
var start = "<p class=\"how-pkg\">";
var p0 = source.IndexOf(start);
var p1 = source.IndexOf("</p>");
var s = source.Substring(p0 + start.Length, p1 - p0);
```

Something like that

Comment: It will actually include <p class=\"how-pkg\"> in the output.

Comment: This is wrong.. This gets output as a `<p class="how-pkg"> leo diam viverra velit,`

Comment: Now it won't work if there is `</p>` somewhere before `<p class=\"how-pkg\">` in the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce rutrum, neque eu varius placerat, <p class=\"how-pkg\"> leo diam viverra velit, </p> a commodo nibh metus nec orci. Nulla pharetra ut augue quis blandit.";
int start = s.IndexOf("<p class=\"how-pkg\">") + 20;
int end = s.IndexOf("</p>", start);

string result = s.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your tag structure is always going to be the same then you can use regex to extract the value like this:

```
    var result = Regex.Match("<p class="how-pkg">hello</p>", "(?<=<p class="how-pkg">).*(?=</p>)").Value;
```

If your tag structure will change then you can capture both tag and values with named groups like this:

```
    <(?<tag>\.*)>(?<text>.*)</\k<tag>>
```

To capture just the value `hello` from `<one>hello</one>`:

```
    (?<=<.*>).*(?=</\w*>)
```

eg.

```
    var result = Regex.Match("<p class="how-pkg">hello</p>", "(?<=<.*>).*(?=</\w*>)").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

- search for `<p` (or `<p class`)
- search for `>` after that - you found a tag (disregards of specified class) and opening point
- (optinal) check if you support this class
- search for `</p>` - you found result and the point where continue search (if necessary).